# Can I use sharp with multer to resize an image and save to disk in a single operation?

Tags: node.js, express, fs, multer, sharp

I'm having some trouble understanding the relationship between sharp and multer.

Currently I'm using multer to extract the image from the req and save it to disk. Works great:

```
const upload = Multer({
  dest: './companyImages',
  fileFilter,
  limits: {
    fileSize: MAX_SIZE
  }
})

router
  .route('/images')
  .post(passportJWT, upload.array('files'), ImageUploadController.saveImage)
```

I can see how I can use sharp to read the file from disk or a stream and resize it,save it to disk as a 2nd file. I would then use fs.unlink to delete the 1st file.

```
sharp('./companyImages/0d928a1a10f462f33b8fed1ea1a20eec.png')
  .resize(300, 200)
  .toFile('output.jpg', function(err) {
    // output.jpg is a 300 pixels wide and 200 pixels high image
    // containing a scaled and cropped version of input.jpg
  });
```

I'd much rather just pass the output from multer to sharp and then go to disk with sharp.

The problem - I haven't determined how to direct multer's output to anything other than a destination on the disk. I'm looking for thoughts and examples & thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, did you solve it? I am VERY stuck with this. I don't know how to send to dest in multer with the file resolution reduced

Comment: i have the same problem too , have you figured it out  yet ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon for `multer` can do it for you in [here](https://github.com/mertdogar/multer-resizer) but don't use `sharp` for resize. This is an example

```
const multer = require('multer');
const MulterResizer = require('multer-resizer');
const resizer = new MulterResizer({
    multer: multer({storage: multer.diskStorage({destination: './'})}),
    tasks: [
        {
            resize: {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080,
                suffix: 'resized-big'
            }
        },
        {
            resize: {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                suffix: 'resized-small'
            }
        },
        {
            cover: {
                width: 160,
                height: 112,
                suffix: 'thumbnail'
            }
        }
    ]
});

router.post('/', auth.ensureAuthentication, resizer.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    // All multer-resizer tasks were completed
});
```

Comment: Update: I'm working through your proposed answer. The multer-resizer module install has not gone smoothly unfortunately...